# NSDate Daylight time saving

Tags: ios, nsdate

I need to know if we can determine that a particular date had Daylighttime saving ON or OFF.

For eg. In Germany , Daylighttime saving was not there from 1950-1979. Can I determine this programmatically in iOS if these days did not have Daylighttime saving?

Comment: `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pick a date and test it.  The NSDate accounts for daylight savings.

Answer (score 0):

isDaylightSavingTimeForDate: returns YES if daylight savings time was in effect *at that moment in time*. If you want to check whether it was in effect in a certain country in a certain year, create an NSDate on 1st of July of that year, and an NSDate on 1st of January of that year, and if neither date had daylight savings time on, then the country didn't have it at all.

(You need to check a date in January as well because Australia, New Zealand etc. have daylight savings time in Summer = January).

iOS is quite good with that kind of historical knowledge. Actually, there are quite a few posts from time to time where iOS has some bizarre but correct information about a timezone and people think it's a bug.